# How to fetch two Properties one with value and another with only property name within same object in ReamDB?

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform, jdbcrealm, realm-database

with RealmDB object how to write multiple keys query ?
Schema Part:

> StudentSchemaNames.student_data = { classID: int, students:
> Students[], noOfPresence: int, noOfabsence: int, noOfLeft: int } ;
>
> StudentScehmaNames.students = {studentid:int, studentfirstName:
> string:, studentlastName:string}

I am having an object like;

> studentDetails = [{"classID": "001", "students": [Array],
> "noOfPresence": 30, "noOfabsence": 2, "noOfLeft": 9}];

currently I am fetching details basic on studentId= 001 ;

> studentDetails = await RealmDB.get(StudentSchemaNames.student_DATA,
> `studentId="${studentId}" AND 'noOfPresence'`);

here student ID property is passed with value and noOfPresence only property name and no value in query to be executed.

but I wanted to write query like ;
Scenario1: Fetch data basis on student ID with value and NoOfPresence only Property
Scenario2: Fetch data basis on students property only with student id value
Scenario3: Fetch data basis on class Property only with student id value

help me out to write queries for above scenario with RealmDB. Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you asking how to write and AND query? So you wand to get back students matching two criteria like classId="${classID}" AND noOfPresence ="${noOfPresence}"?

Comment: @Jay, Thank you but as per RealmDB document do we have to pass the values also in query or we can execute query with only properties ?

Comment: I don't understand the comment question. How does one *pass the values also in query*? What does *execute query with only properties* refer to? Perhaps you can update the question with code examples of what that means?